# SQL Query to find Total Occurence of a "number" in a Column

Tags: sql

I want to know the SQL Query to find how many times a particular number is repeating(total count) in a column which is of int type.

Example: Coumn_iD = PostalCode

```
Postalcode
8696
2314
9645
3268
4288
2222
```

in the above case count of 8 = 4, Query for 2  should return 7
Like that, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: In which radix :)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the number of occurrences of the `particularSymbol` on each row in the table as `LENGTH(columnName) - LENGTH(REPLACE(columnName, particularNumber, ""))` and then simply sum those over the whole table:

```
SELECT SUM(LENGTH(columnName) - LENGTH(REPLACE(columnName, particularNumber, '')))
FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 1):

First count the number of occurrences for each row (the nested SELECT statement), then sum up that count to get one aggregate number.

```
DECLARE @my_num INT
SET @my_num = 2

SELECT SUM(count_per_row)
FROM
    (
    SELECT len(Postalcode) - len(replace(Postalcode,@my_num,''))  as count_per_row
    FROM table)
```

If you don't need to generalize it, then just replace @my_num in the SELECT block with your number of interest (and get rid of the SELECT statement).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the database system you are using.

In Postgres you can create one row for each character in the postalcode and then group by that:

```
with test_data (postalcode) as (
  values ('8696'),('2314'),('9645'),('3268'),('4288'),('2222')
)
select c, count(*)
from test_data, unnest(string_to_array(postalcode, null)) as t(c)
group by c
order by c
```

Answer (score 0):

Ivo solution is probably the best.  However, because the postal codes are only 4 digits, you might find this easier to follow:

```
select sum(case when postalcode like '2222' then 4
                when postalcode like '%2%2%2%' then 3
                when postalcode like '%2%2%' then 2
                when postalcode like '%2%' then 1
                else 0
           end) as num_2s
from t;
```